# How I can set Mutiny String variable data into class variable?

Tags: redhat, quarkus, reactive, mutiny

[Attached image show the code I have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5TO9.png)  I have a method that returns a String amount and I have stored that amount in `var1` variable of Mutiny String. I print `var1` variable, now I want to set `var1` variable in `DataMODEL` Pojo like DTO class and this class have amount variable. I don't know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like:

```
@POST
@Path("/filterObject")
public Uni<Response> nameUni(DataMODEL dataMODEL) {
    return dataBaService.getAmountIntoAccount(dataMODEL).onItem().invoke(s -> {
        dataMODEL.amount = s
    });
}
```

Comment: i solve this problem from this way
https://github.com/alihaider8480/Put-Uni-String-Data-To-Class-Variable/blob/master/2.png